# como activar una función al hacer scroll y bajar hasta un componente especifico en Angular 7

Tags: angular, scroll

como puedo hacer para que al bajar en una pagina se active alguna funcion usando angular 7 ? he leido la documentacion y no encuentro algun evento o funcion que me pueda ayudar con esto, ademas consegui este tutorial: http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2018/06/evento-scroll-angular.html pero no funciona, da un error el cual mencionan en sus comentarios. la idea es esta, tengo una pagina, por ejemplo, algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde cada color es un contenedor, suponiendo que se hace scroll hasta bajar al contenedor de color amarillo, lo que quiero es que cuando se baje al contenedor de color amarillo se active cierta funcion. como podria lograr eso usando angular ? Quiero lograr algo como lo hacen en esta pagina:  https://www.athenos.com/  Gracias de antemano a todo el que me pueda ayudar. Saludos!

Comment: Entré a ver el error del cual hablas. ¿Ya intentaste buscar ese error en la comunidad inglesa? Encontré [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget) Me parece que ese es el error que tienes. Me dices cómo te va con eso. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @LuisGerónimo gracias por responder, eso no soluciono mi problema. en realidad ando buscando alguien que haya trabajado con el manejo del scroll en Angular y haya hecho algo como lo que necesito, porque en la documentación no mencionan nada al respecto, y en San Google he buscado y no he podido lograr lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

hay una librería que te puede ayudar con eso.

instala

```
npm install --save ng-in-viewport@next intersection-observer
```

importala (puede que en al AppModule)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { InViewportModule } from 'ng-in-viewport';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        InViewportModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

luego usa la directiva.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item inactive"
        inViewport
        [inViewportOptions]="{ threshold: [0] }"
        (inViewportAction)="onIntersection($event)"
        *ngFor="let item of items;">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

COMPONENTE:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    public readonly items: number[] = Array(1000).fill(1).map((item, index) => item + index);

    public onIntersection({ target, visible }: { target: Element; visible: boolean }): void {
          console.log(target, visible);
          //aca ves si el elemento aparecio en tu pantalla o se fue de tu pantalla
    }
}
```

Si quieres mas ejemplos o informacion aca tienes el [repo de la libreria](https://github.com/k3nsei/ng-in-viewport):

Comment: Estoy leyendo desde el teléfono, en un momento la reviso. Pero pregunto... Eso me serviría para activar una funcion cuándo el scroll baja a un contenedor específico? Y no durante todo el scroll?

Comment: solo disparara el evento cuando el contenedor entre o salga de tu viewport(lo que el usuario ve) y te enviara la referencia al elemento y si esta visible (entro al viewport) o no (salio del viewport)

Comment: Chévere! Voy a probarlo, te comentare como me va.

Comment: hola amigo, logre hacer lo que queria con esa libreria que me pasaste. Ahora el detalle es que solo quiero que se ejecute una vez, para eso intento meter el codigo dentro del ngOnInit pero me muestra errores, sabras como puedo hacer meter el metodo dentro del ngOnInit para asi poder lograr que solo se ejcute una vez cuando la pagina carga ?

Comment: el nematodo siempre se ejecutara ya que es un listener a un evento. eso no lo puedes parar. lo que puedes hacer es un flag (crea un atributo en el componente e inicialo en false) y cuando se ejecute onIntersection cambia su valor a true y escribe una validación en el método que se ejecute tu lógica solo si ese flag es false.

Comment: Ok, ya te entendi. dentro de un contenedor padre tengo 2 contenedores hijos a los que debo aplicar el mismo efecto cuando el contenedor padre entra en el viewport, debo tener 2 lineas como estas:  class="list-item inactive"
        inViewport
        [inViewportOptions]="{ threshold: [0] }"
        (inViewportAction)="onIntersection($event)" en cada contenedor hijo ? asi lo tengo en este momento pero me parece que no es una buena forma.