# como puedo hacer para usar jquery en angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

necesito usar funciones de jquery en angular, instale jquery con npm install jquery, tambien tengo el cdn en el index.html y tengo esta linea en la componente donde quiero usar la funcion:

```js
declare var $:any;
```

y no me funciona, este es el codigo que estoy colocando para probar algo:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on("click", function(){
      alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
  });
```

sin embargo me salen estos errores:

```js
ERROR in src/app/nosotros/nosotros.component.ts(18,14): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
src/app/nosotros/nosotros.component.ts(18,21): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
src/app/nosotros/nosotros.component.ts(22,4): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
```

no se que mas debo hacer para pode usar jquery en Angular.

Comment: Explica por que necesitas jquery en Angular. no lo necesitas.

Comment: Eso que coloque fue un simple ejemplo de lo que necesito. En realidad lo que necesito es hacer que cuando el Scroll baje hasta un contenedor especifico se active una función pero se me ha hecho imposible lograr eso, estaba probando con eso que coloque, pero en realidad lo que quiero lograr es eso, en la documentación de angular solo nombran un evento scroll y no explican mas acerca de el.

Comment: necesito lograr que aparezca un texto cuando se baje hasta un contenedor especifico, algo asi como hacen en esta pagina:  https://www.athenos.com

Comment: acá hice una respuesta a esa pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291826/como-activar-una-funci%c3%b3n-al-hacer-scroll-y-bajar-hasta-un-componente-especifico/293209#293209

Comment: `hostlistener` te permite escuchar los eventos globales tales como el scroll", puede que eso te sea más util y a la larga, dentro de angular, te causara menos conflictos. Angular no suele llevarse muy bien con jquery ya que no puede detectar ningún evento producido por este sin hacks enredosos.

Comment: Esta pregunta es un ejemplo de [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY). Lo que realmente necesitas preguntar (en mi opinión) es cómo lograr esa funcionalidad usando Angular, en lugar de intentar insertar jQuery para hacerlo. Te aseguro que por este camino sólo encontrarás más problemas, jQuery y Angular no se llevan bien porque ambos necesitan tener el control total de la página para funcionar correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

No es muy conveniente usar angular(versión 2 en adelante) con jquery por eso fue reescrito prácticamente totalmente

para lograr el comportamiento que necesitas simplemente puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Dentro de tu archivo .ts crear una función

```
miFuncion():void{
  alert("The paragraph was clicked.")
}
```

y en el html agregar tu funcion al evento click

```
<p (click)="miFuncion()">Click para funcionar</p>
```

Con todo esto lograrías lo mismo que con jquery

Comment: Eso que coloque fue un simple ejemplo de lo que necesito. En realidad lo que necesito es hacer que cuando el Scroll baje hasta un contenedor especifico se active una función pero se me ha hecho imposible lograr eso, estaba probando con eso que coloque, pero en realidad lo que quiero lograr es eso, en la documentación de angular solo nombran un evento scroll y no explican mas acerca de el.

Comment: necesito lograr que aparezca un texto cuando se baje hasta un contenedor especifico, algo asi como hacen en esta pagina:  https://www.athenos.com

Comment: Creo que esto te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977888/onscroll-event-triggers-function-in-angular4

Comment: Ese post ya lo había visto, lo implementé y solo me funciona con window:scroll y no obtengo el resultado que quiero ya que la función se invoca cada vez que se hace scroll, lo que necesito es que se active solo cuando se hace scroll y se llega a un contenedor específico, probe con solamente 'scroll' y no hace nada.

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir en el archivo `angular.json`, en la seccion `scripts`, dentro de la seccion `build` (puedes añadirlo tambien en la seccion `test` si la tienes y lo necesitas), la ruta correspondiente a tu archivo `js` de `jQuery`. Debe quedar algo similar a:

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

**Nota:** en principio no hace falta la referencia en el `index.html`