# Como Indentifico el Elemento en el que se encuentra el scroll posicionado en angular?

Tags: html, angular, div

Poseo varios `div` que contienen varios parrafos de texto y intento realizar es que cuando el scroll salga de un  `div`cambiar una propiedad del mismo como el color por ejemplo.

```
<div id="texto1">
 <!-- Texto largo -->
</div>
<div id="texto2">
 <!-- Texto largo -->
</div>
<div id="texto3">
 <!-- Texto largo -->
</div>
```

Revise la siguiente pregunta para poder realizar una accion cuando sale el scroll de un  `div` e ingresa a otro
[como activar una función al hacer scroll y bajar hasta un componente especifico en Angular 7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291826/como-activar-una-funci%C3%B3n-al-hacer-scroll-y-bajar-hasta-un-componente-especifico)
Ahora intento identificar cual es el `div` del que salio el scroll

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza [Angular Material CdkScrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview). Además de que te permite optimizar el render de tus elementos, trae consigo utilidades para el evento scrolling de estos.

Es muy sencillo de instalar solo es necesario `npm install @angular/cdk --save`.

Si decides optar por esta librería te puede servir de referencia el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from "@angular/cdk/scrolling";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  //Arreglo de elementos a mostrar
  items = Array.from({ length: 100000 }).map((_, i) => {
    return { item: `Item #${i}`, clazz: "none" };
  });

  //Obtenemos la referencia del virutal-scroll cdk
  @ViewChild("scrollingCdk", { static: true })
  scrollingCdk: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  ngOnInit() {
   //Nos suscribimos al cambio de indice durante el evento scrolling
    this.scrollingCdk.scrolledIndexChange.subscribe(index => {
      console.log(index);
      //Hacemos el cambio de clases de colores
      if (index - 1 >= 0) {
        this.items[index - 1].clazz = "read";
      }
      this.items[index].clazz = "current";
      this.items[index + 1].clazz = "none";
    });
  }
}
```

Por otra parte en nuestro html.

```html
<!-- [itemSize]="100" este valor es el tamaño del item en pixeles -->
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport #scrollingCdk [itemSize]="100" class="example-viewport">
    <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items;">
        <div class="example-item-detail" [ngClass]="item.clazz">Item: {{item.item}} Class:{{item.clazz}}</div>
    </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

De igual manera te dejo el ejemplo completo [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrolling-event-cdk?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Te recomiendo darle una leída a la documentación, tal vez puedas implementar una mejor solución.

Comment: Oscar tienes una idea de como utilizar el virtual scroll con un endpoint que viene paginado?

Comment: Me refiero a cuando detecte que se acabaron los elementos, haga el fetch de la segunda pagina y añada esos nuevos items... y así sucesivamente hasta la ultima página.

Comment: En los [ejemplos del cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview), viene un paginado que simula un `fetch` del server, tal vez te puede ayudar, [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/angular/empojvyrqqx?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-data-source-example.ts) el ejemplo.

Comment: Cierto que fatal error mío no revisar la doc... creí haberla revisado bien. Muchas gracias Oscar.

Comment: por cierto oscar, tienes trabajo de front acá en mexico?

Comment: Gracias Me sirvio mucho estaba utilizando un @HostListener pero con la libreria que me indicaste "@angular/cdk/scrolling"; hizo todo mas sencilo

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Me sirvio mucho estaba utilizando un  `@HostListener` pero con la libreria que me indicaste `"@angular/cdk/scrolling";` hizo todo mas sencilo